# Trying to edit installed files in RAM during a live CD Ubuntu session

Tags: linux, memory, ubuntu, minecraft

I'm without a hard drive for the moment, and would like to install some mods on minecraft inside of my Ubuntu live usb. Unfortunately I can't find the files once minecraft has installed (and works).

Are the files (the .minecraft folder) hidden away in the RAM like I suspect? Can I access them somehow? DDD for GDB was suggested, is this the right way to go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cnicutar is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623514/377270), there's no reason to try for `gdb` or `ddd`. Neat tools, overpowered for this task.

`strace(1)` is also pretty neat and a bit more appropriate, but I think there's an easier way: find where writable content can actually be written.

Chances are good the output of `mount` or `cat /proc/mounts` or `cat /proc/self/mounts` will show you a mounted filesystem that is writable. Start looking *there*. Try `find /path/to/writable/mount -iname '*minecraft*' -print` if you're confident that the files will be named with a `minecraft` in them. (`-iname` for case-insensitive matching.) If minecraft files have a common extension, you could search for that instead.

Comment: Thanks! I got a lot of weird entries with cat `cat /proc/self/mounts` but `find /path/to/writable/mount -iname '*minecraft*' -print` worked really well when I used it with root '/'. I found out that the folder I was looking for was simply hidden... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GDB and DDD will be of much use. I would use `strace` and pour over the output to see what the process `open(2)`s.

For instance it often happens that I run something that's so poorly documented I can't find the list of files it tries to read on startup. It's just easier to `strace` and see it for myself.

Comment: Thanks, strace seems really useful, although I wasn't able to get it working with this problem I'll keep it in mind next time I need to debug something without sourcecode.